# Proof verification of if $\{x_n\}$ is monotone then $\{y_n\} = {1\over x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}$ is monotone

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, inequality, monotone-functions

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and $\{x_n\}$ is a monotone sequence.
>   Prove that:
>   $$
> \{y_n\} = {1\over x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}
> $$
>   is also a monotone sequence.

Given $\{x_n\}$ is monotone then by definition:
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb N:x_n \le x_{n+1} \tag1
$$
or:
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb N:x_n \ge x_{n+1} \tag2
$$
Let's prove for $(1)$ first. Using definition of a monotone sequence:
$$
x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le \dots \le x_n
$$
So from this:
$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n \le x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n + x_{n+1} \tag 3
$$
Thus taking the reciprocal of $(3)$ we get that:

$$
{1\over x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n} \ge {1\over x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n + x_{n+1}}
$$
But LHS is $y_n$ and RHS of the inequality is $y_{n+1}$, therefore by definition of a monotone sequence we conclude that $y_n$ is also monotone.

Case $(2)$ is obtained similarly. What bugs me is that the following still holds (at least for $x_n \ge 0$):

$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n \le x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n + x_{n+1}
$$

And we get once again that:

$$
{1\over x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n} \ge {1\over x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \dots + x_n + x_{n+1}}
$$

But how is this possible? From the above it looks like $y_n$ is always monotonically decreasing, which seems false. For example when $\sum_{k=1}^nx_k < 1$.

Where have i taken the wrong road?

**Update**

As shown in answers and comments monotonicity is only preserved assuming all $x_n$ have the same sign.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. For $x_n>0$ it's obvious.

Comment: Inequality (3) has nothing to do with the fact that $\{x_i\}$ is a monotone sequence. It holds for any set of positive numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence $-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,4,5,\dots$ is monotone, the sequence of the partial sums $-3,-5,-6,-6,-5,-3,1,6,\dots$ is **not** monotone, and the sequence of the reciprocals of the partial sums is still not monotone.

For such sequences the  monotone property is preserved if the $x$s have all the same sign!

Comment: So $x_n$ is monotone does not imply $y_n$ is monotone, right? And hence such a proof may not be obtained, at least without additional assumptions on $x_n$

Comment: Yes, that's right. Even tha partial sums are not monotone!

Comment: The problem makes sense onlu for $x_i\gt0$.

Comment: Yes, if the $x$s have all the same sign then the monotone property is preserved.

Comment: @Oldboy well I agree with you, though the author didn't put in any constraints for $x_n$. I'm going to stick to $x_n > 0$. Otherwise it makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

You mistakenly assume (in case (1) and in case (2) alike) that $x\le y$ implies $\frac1x\ge\frac1y$, whereas this is the case only if $xy>0$. Consider the sequence $x_1=-6$, $x_2=2$, $x_3=3$, $x_4=4$, and then whatever.

Answer (score 1):

For $x_i>0$, it's trivial:

$$y_n = {1\over x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}$$

$$y_{n+1} = {1\over x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n + x_{n+1}}$$

$$y_{n+1} -y_n= {1\over x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n + x_{n+1}}-{1\over x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n}$$

$$y_{n+1} -y_n= {-x_{n+1} \over (x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n + x_{n+1})(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_n)}<0$$

$$y_{n+1} <y_n$$